# Java/Jmeter connect timeout but not on browser (Not a JMeter issue)

Tags: java, networking

In windows 2003 using JDK 1.7_21

So I setup Jemeter on my desktop to do an HTTP request to a specific URL and it works fine. But when I try from another machine I get a connect timeout.

The URL works fine in the I.E browser and I can also ping the domain from the command line. But for wahat ever reason the JVM doesn't want to connect.

In fact this is to test a sample HTTPClient I wrote. it's not the code because the code works off the desktop but on the server environment the JVM wont connect, proof JMeter wont either. but the browser and pings works.

I suspect java is getting it's network settings from somewhere different??? Proxy???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. is IE/Windows using a proxy? You can check by going to to Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings

[image: How to access Proxy settings in IE]

If it is, you can set some JVM properties so that your Java application uses a proxy, there a couple ways of doing that, one way is through the command line when you execute it, you can use something similar to:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=your.proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=your.proxy.port -jar your.jar
```

or

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=your.proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=your.proxy.port YourMainClass
```

Comment: Ok so my server network is setup correctly and the browser had proxy settings and that's why it was working in the browser. The external I.P I was trying to access is hosted in the network and the network does not allow to go out and in. My admin gave me another gateway to try. It all works. No proxy settings required. Thanks for the idea though.